# Swing UI for a test Websocket client

Tags: java, beginner, mvc, swing

I am new to Java's Swing and built a test client that connects to a server. I was wondering if my use of a `Controller` class as a link between the classes `ClientWindow` and `WebsocketService` made sense and would be thankful for comments. (I can take it, so the more my code is criticized the happier I am.)

---

For the sake of brevity, I have omitted most methods and fields.

**ClientWindow**

```
public class ClientWindow implements ActionListener {
    private static final String USER_ID = "19";
    private final IController controller;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        controller.connectAs(USER_ID);
    }

    public void addMessage(String line) {
        responseArea.setText( responseArea.getText() + line );
    }
}
```

**DefaultController** (implements `IController`)

```
public class DefaultController implements IController {

    protected WebsocketService wsService;
    protected ClientWindow display;

    public DefaultController() {
        wsService = new WebsocketService(this);
    }

    public void setDisplay(IClientDisplay display) {
        this.display = display;
    }

    // ------------------
    // IController methods
    @Override
    public void updateMessage(String message) {
        if (display != null) {
            display.addMessage(message);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void connectAs(String userId) {
        wsService.connectToServer(userId);
    }
}
```

**WebsocketService**

```
@ClientEndpoint
public class WebsocketService {
    private final IController controller;
    private String userId;

    public WebsocketService(IController controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
    }

    /**
     * On open: register the session and signal
     * the user ID and to the Node.js server.
     * @param session The WebSocket session
     */
    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        this.session = session;
        controller.updateMessage("Connected to server");
        send( "c:" + userId);
    }

    /**
     * On message: handle incoming message by
     * invoking methods of the controller. 
     * @param message
     */
    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message) {
        controller.updateMessage(message);
    }

    /**
     * Open a WebSocket to connect to the Node.js server.
     */
    public void connectToServer(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
        WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
        try {
            container.connectToServer(this, new URI(Commons.SERVER_ADDR));
        }
        // catch blocks
    }
}
```

Finally, **Client**

```
public class Client {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DefaultController controller = new DefaultController();
        controller.setDisplay(new ClientWindow(controller));
    }
}
```

---

`Client` definitely looks bad, especially that second line. I might as well skip the `DefaultController` and just have a field for `ClientWindow` in `WebsocketService` and vice versa but that's obviously a big *no-no*. I have looked into MVC but I don't really have much to model (or am I wrong?).

After all, I need to be able to give commands to my Service but also to display output from it at any given time (`onMessage`) and so this was the most elegant solution I could think of.

Comment: I haven't looked at this in too much detail, but that random hard coded "19" looks pretty smelly. I can see later it's a userId, but whose?

Comment: @raptortech97 Aha, definitely :) It's just a stupid example so I don't have to post the code to get the input from the user, which is not relevant to my question.

Comment: I wanted to review this but I genuinely can't think of any improvements to what I see here. Good job :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I'm not too familiar with GUIs nor MVC, but I guess your model contains at least a string (which is displayed in the `responseArea`). You might put that into a separate model class.

   Another thing is a websocket service which I try to hide behind the model and separate it from the controller class. [Wikipedia says the following about MVC's model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller):

   > A *model* notifies its associated views and controllers when there has been a change in its state.

   So, the websocket service could notify the model, then the model would notify the view about the change.
2. I'd rename `IController` to `Controller`.

   *Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*, *Chapter 2: Meaningful Names*, p24:

   > **Interfaces and Implementations**
   >
   > These are sometimes a special case for encodings. For example, say you are building an
   >   ABSTRACT FACTORY for the creation of shapes. This factory will be an interface and will
   >   be implemented by a concrete class. What should you name them? `IShapeFactory` and
   >   `ShapeFactory`? I prefer to leave interfaces unadorned. The preceding `I`, so common in
   >   today’s legacy wads, is a distraction at best and too much information at worst. I don’t
   >   want my users knowing that I’m handing them an interface. I just want them to know that
   >   it’s a `ShapeFactory`. So if I must encode either the interface or the implementation, I choose
   >   the implementation. Calling it `ShapeFactoryImp`, or even the hideous `CShapeFactory`, is 
   >   preferable to encoding the interface.
3. I think `WebsocketService` should not know anything about `Controller.connectAs`. Currently it violates the [interface-segregation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle). You could create a `WebsocketCallback` interface which your controller *implementation* class could implement:

   ```
   public interface WebsocketCallback {
       void updateMessage(String message);
   }

   public class DefaultController implements Controller, WebsocketCallback {
       ...
   }
   ```

   I guess implementing it by the model class could be even better (see #1).
4. I would rename the parameter here to `message` to express its purpose and make the code easier to understand:

   > ```
   > public void updateMessage(String string) {
   > ```
5. I would throw here an exception instead of hiding the error:

   > ```
   > @Override
   > public void updateMessage(String message) {
   >     if (display != null) {
   >         display.addMessage(message);
   >     }
   > }
   > ```

   Crash early. It is rather a bug in the code when it is called without setting the `display` before which you shouldn't hide. It would help debugging: having a stacktrace usually better than just an one-line bugreport: "the button does not do anything" or something similar. See also: *The Pragmatic Programmer: From Journeyman to Master* by *Andrew Hunt* and *David Thomas*: *Dead Programs Tell No Lies*.
6. If responseArea if a `JTextArea` instance, you could use `append` instead of `setText(getText() ...)` here:

   > ```
   > responseArea.setText( responseArea.getText() + line );
   > ```

Comment: Beautiful answer, many thanks for your time!